# Find second digit from string and replace with new digit

Tags: jquery, regex

I have following string example. I want to find second digit from string and replace with other random digit. I have random digit but problem is find second digit and replace with new digit. How achieve this?

```
1. "data[KPI][0][rows][0][name]"
2. "data[KPI][0][rows][1][name]"
3. "data[KPI][0][rows][2][name]"
```

**Expected Output**

```
1. "data[KPI][0][rows][4][name]"
2. "data[KPI][0][rows][5][name]"
3. "data[KPI][0][rows][6][name]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\d+(?=[^\d]*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/uV3aL0/32

```
var re = /\d+(?=[^\d]*$)/gim;
var str = 'data[KPI][0][rows][0][name]\ndata[KPI][0][rows][1][name]\ndata[KPI][0][rows][2][name]';
var subst = '';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Can you give full code to replace second digit? Your answer find second digit but how to replace it?

Comment: It gives me empty array `data[KPI][0][rows][][name]` instead of random digit.

Comment: @Sadikhasan you need to use subst of your choice....as of now it's empty...see s code

Comment: Thanks it's working fine for me.I got solution from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hey please try this one:

```
 var str="data[KPI][0][rows][0][name]";
 var Result=  str.replace(/(\[\d\]\[[^\]]+\])\[\d\]/, "$1[YourCharTo Replace]");
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps,

**Java-Script way**

```
var mystr    = "data[KPI][0][rows][0][name]";

var regex       = /(data\[\D{1,}\[\d{1,}]\[\D{1,}\])(\[\d{0,}])(\[\D{0,}])/;

console.log(mystr.replace(regex,"$1[DesiredNumber]$3"));
```

**PHP Way**

```
$str          = "data[KPI][0][rows][0][name]";

$regex        = "/(data\[\D{1,}\[\d{1,}]\[\D{1,}\])(\[\d{0,}])(\[\D{0,}])/";

$replacements =  '${1}[YourNumber]${3}';

echo preg_replace($regex, $replacements, $str);
```